# Security for Customer Portal

Tags: community

I have customers with multiple locations/subsidiaries (account hierarchy) who need to view/access information in those related accounts.  I have looked at sharing rules, but have too many accounts, and fear I'll exceed the 300 per object limit.  What's the best way to set this up?

I want customers from a parent Account to be able to see records of all their child and grandchild Accounts, but none of the customers in the child Accounts to be able to see records from either their parent's Account or any sibling's Accounts that might exist.

Example: Customer ABC, has subsidiary DEF, which has subsidiary GHI. ABC has another subsidiary named JKL that's a sibling of DEF. I want contacts at ABC to see records at their account and all subsidiaries.  Subsidiary DEF contacts should see their records and GHI records, but not the records of their parent company ABC or their sibling JKL. GHI contacts should see their records, but not the records of their parent DEF or their grandparent ABC, nor their parent's sibling JKL. Contacts at JKL should only see their own records and no others, including not being able to see the records of their parent company ABC. In essence, no contact sees anything except their own company's records and the records of a child company.

How can we accomplish this kind of record sharing in a customer community?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you  wanting GHI contacts to be able to see DEF and ABC records? If not, what are you asking?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Let me try again.  Company ACME International (the headquarters) wants their community users to be able to view records belonging to ACME International, plus records belonging to ACME EMEA, plus ACME Jordan.  ACME EMEA community users can see ACME EMEA records plus ACME Jordan records, but NOT ACME International records.  ACME Jordan community users can see ACME Jordan records, but NOT ACME International or ACME EMEA.

Comment: You want a parent to be able to see the records of all children (and presumably grandchildren), but none of the children to be able to see either the parent's or sibling's records? Would that be an accurate summary of what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, that would be an accurate summary.  Not sure how to accomplish that with community users.

Comment: I'm going to update your question for you. What if anything have you tried? The issue you face is that Customer Communities don't have roles, and therefore no hierarchy support in the traditional sense. For what you want to do, it sounds as though you may need to have a Partner Community. Hopefully someone will have a good idea on how to set it up.

Comment: Thank you.  I am investigating Partner Community as an option.  The sharing rules was my hope initially, but the limit on that struck that option down.

Comment: I have triggers controlling my sharing between Partners and the Group they are in

Comment: At my last company, we had a huge body of custom Apex code to manage the relationships among HV portal users: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_about_HVPUs.htm&language=en_US ... What we ended up doing is treating the user profile as a "role" and then we reinvented the wheel with Apex sharing rules. I don't recommend this - it was expensive, slow, and an absolute pain to maintain - but it did work.

Comment: It seems to me this is not something one would want to implement for all their customers; instead, only those who have this kind of hierarchy. The cost of partner licenses would seem to poorly spent on other customers. Is the loss of Chatter interaction between one's other customers an issue worth considering if splitting into separate Partner and Customer Communities when they're not "traditional Partners"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we had a similar requirement.  We built a 2 level hierarchy sharing structure for Partner Accounts/Contacts records.

One Partner Account is the Parent Account to any number of Child Accounts.  Within that hierarchy, the user(s) in the Parent Account will be able to access data that otherwise will only be accessed by user in the Child account(s) but the Child Account users will not be able to access data associated with the Parent Account.   Nor will the Child account users be able to access the other Child accounts data.

The parent account’s user(s) will have the manager role and any number of other accounts’ user(s) will have the User role.  Each group of users would require a **new** account to support sharing by role.  There will be more than 1 group of partners which follow this model, so you will need a new “Role Sharing” master account to support role based sharing for each.

Comment: We will be taking the route of utilizing account teams, where the users in the parent account are assigned via trigger to an account team with access to the child account and so forth down the line.